# Open GL Depth and Alpha issues

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I am rendering two triangles in GL. The bottom two vertices of each have a set alpha value to make them transparent. I am using Depth testing and Alpha blending defined by the following calls

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glDepthRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE);
glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_ONE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.1f);
```

This is the result I get:
[image: triangles]

I expect to see the top of the second triangle through the transparent pixels of the first triangle however it appears to be cut off by the depth test. The background color also appears more transparent over the triangles (some blending issue?)

How can I render this as expected?

**Edit:**

If I disable writing to the depth buffer and draw the triangles in back-to-front order I get the following result. Notice how the background is more transparent over the triangle, and the white line at the tip of the second triangle. Some definite blending issues here.

[image: triangles2]

Comment: Do you try to achieve order-independent transparency?

Comment: Many people, when first learning OpenGL, notice how easy it is to just draw a bunch of triangles any-which-way and get exactly the result they want. They are then disappointed when this doesn't work for transparent triangles. Unfortunately that is just how it is. It lets you send rendering comments to a GPU - it's not a complete game engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two things to solve this:

1. Disable writing to depth buffer and draw triangles based on distance from the camera.
2. Use `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` to fix blending issues.

Below is the final result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Disable writing to the depth buffer:

```
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
```

Then draw the triangles in back-to-front order.

This is not perfect, but it is a typical way to handle transparent objects, and it's very simple.

If you have depth writing enabled and draw front-to-back, the triangle in front will obscure the triangle in back *as if* it were opaque, even though it's not opaque.

Comment: See my edit with these changes in place

Comment: Looks good to me, what is the problem? What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: After much searching I found the correct `glBlendFunc` and posted an answer with all the fixes.